# Actionscript3 XML How to delete XML node by Searching for more than one child?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have this XML:

```
<Lists>
    <Song>
        <SongNumber>0</SongNumber>
        <RealSongNumber>5</RealSongNumber>
        <SongName>Love you</SongName>
        <AlbumNumber>6</AlbumNumber>
    </Song>
    <Song>
        <SongNumber>1</SongNumber>
        <RealSongNumber>3</RealSongNumber>
        <SongName>Love you2</SongName>
        <AlbumNumber>7</AlbumNumber>
    </Song>
</Lists>
```

I need to delete the node `<Song></Song>` and all its children by checking all values of the children so I need to ask:
if SongNumber == 0 && RealSongNumber == 5 && SongName == Love you && AlbumNumber == 6 then delete our parent.

is this possible in AS3

I do not want to delete by index

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
var xml:XML = 
<Lists>
    <Song>
        <SongNumber>0</SongNumber>
        <RealSongNumber>5</RealSongNumber>
        <SongName>Love you</SongName>
        <AlbumNumber>6</AlbumNumber>
    </Song>
<Song>
        <SongNumber>0</SongNumber>
        <RealSongNumber>3</RealSongNumber>
        <SongName>Love you2</SongName>
        <AlbumNumber>7</AlbumNumber>
    </Song>
    <Song>
        <SongNumber>1</SongNumber>
        <RealSongNumber>3</RealSongNumber>
        <SongName>Love you2</SongName>
        <AlbumNumber>7</AlbumNumber>
    </Song>
</Lists>;

delete xml.Song.(elements('SongNumber') == 0 && elements('RealSongNumber') == 5)[0];
trace (xml.toXMLString());
```

Add whatever conditions else that you want.